# Volver a 'x' Activity cuando se cancela / se envía un email

Tags: android, email

Me gustaría saber, si se puede volver a una determinada Activity cuando le das a enviar un email y lo cancelas. Quiero decir, tengo un menú, entro a la opción de formulario, le das a enviar y este automáticamente se sube a la base de datos, y luego se abre la opción de enviar el email. Lo que quiero hacer es que, si no lo envías vuelva al menú, y si lo envías que automáticamente vuelva tambien al menú.. He probado con finish(); y onBackPressed(); pero ninguno me ha funcionado. Conocen alguna forma? Gracias

Editado: [image]

Esta es la foto de mi código, lo del if Familiar, no es importante ya que es una variable dependiendo de lo que selecciones en el formulario. El último if es para que en caso de que haya foto se abra para enviarlo con email. Lo que quiero es que cuando se abra lo del email, en caso de que le de a cancelar, vuelva a mi menú. Y si le doy a enviar, una vez se abra el gmail y se envíe, automáticamente vuelva al menú. Espero se entienda mejor así, gracias.

Comment: intenta explicarlo mejor, pon imágenes de las actividades y el código por las que vas pasando y así nos lo dejarás algo más claro. Si que es posible lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar con una foto del código, si no entiendes dime y pongo alguna foto más o lo intento explicar mejor, gracias.

Comment: Si no me equivoco, desde menu vas a formulario y desde formulario vas a la actividad para enviar el email, con lo cual si despues de llamar al startActivity de email le pones un finish, al cerrar la actividad de mail ya te pasaría a menú

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta pero no lo tengo exactamente así. Yo tengo el menú principal, y una actividad para escribir el formulario. En este formulario relleno los datos, y al final tengo un botón que hace un intent al gmail y abre la pestaña para seleccionar una app de correo.

Comment: Al pulsar el botón para seleccionar el gestor de correo, ponle un finish despues a ver si hace lo que quieres, así te cerrará la actividad formulario y al volver volverás directamente al menú

Comment: el formulario es un DialogFragment? Fragment? Activity?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurre es que cuando estás lanzando el Intent para enviar el correo, quizá no esté entendiendo el finish() de tu activity. 
Prueba a invocar al finish desde fuera del método desde el que se llama a "Enviar Email":

```
//...
enviarMail(); // El método que crea el Intent para enviar el mail
this.finish(); // Fuera y después del método
//...
```

En caso de que no funcione así, puedes probar a meter un delay de unos milisegundos al finish. 
Si eso no funciona lo último que se me ocurre es que generes otro Intent llamando a la actividad a la que quieres volver, aunque si tenías datos cargados de la anterior sesión quizá no te sea conveniente.